# Finding the elementary and power sum symmetric polynomial given complete symmetric polynomial

Tags: power-series, symmetric-polynomials

I have been given the complete symmetric polynomial, $h_n$ as $$h_n = n, \ \ \forall n \geq 1$$

I have to show that the sequence of elementary symmetric polynomials $(e_n)$ and the power sum symmetric polynomial $(p_n)$ are periodic with period $3$ and $6$ respectively.

(Note some unknown values of $x_1,x_2,\cdots$ have been plugged into $h_n,e_n,p_n$.)

We denote the the generating functions of $h_n, \ p_n, \ e_n$ as $H(t),\ P(t),\ E(t)$ respectively, and
$$E(t)H(-t) = 1$$
$$P(t) = \frac{H'(t)}{H(t)}$$

Therefore, I get $$H(t)=\sum_{n \geq 0} h_nt^n = h_0 +\sum_{n \geq 1} nt^n = 1+\frac{t}{(1-t)^2} = \frac{1+t^2 - t}{(1-t)^2}$$
$$\implies E(t)=\frac{(1+t)^2}{1+t^2 + t}=\frac{(1-t)(1+t)^2}{1-t^3}$$
$$\implies P(t)=\frac{1+t}{(1-t)(1+t^2 - t)}=\frac{(1+t)^2}{(1-t)(1+t^3)}$$
Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Addendum: This is a question that appears in Macdonald's Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials, all notations are borrowed from that text. You can find an image of the original question below:

[image]

Comment: How does the equation $h_n=n$ make sense, given that $h_n$ is a polynomial in some variables and $n$ is just a number? (Also, isn't $h_n$ called the complete *homogeneous* symmetric polynomial?) What does it mean for a polynomial to be "periodic"?

Comment: On your first point: I didn't really give that much thought, it's a question straight out of a text, which I've now mentioned in my question. Second point: Might very well be called that as well, I used the same terminology as used in the aforementioned text. Third point: My mistake, I didn't mean the polynomials being periodic, but the sequence of polynomials indexed by $n$ being periodic which I've corrected in the question now

Comment: It still makes no sense. The homogeneous polynomials are certainly not constants and the elementary and power sum symmetric polynomials definitely do not form periodic sequences. My only guess is you are leaving out important context (like maybe the polynomials are being evaluated at some values or something?) or misunderstanding the text. You also didn't say *where* in the text this comes from.

Comment: I have attached an image of the question as it appears in the books, if that helps

Comment: As you can see in the very first exercise, the exercises are talking about situations where *specific values are assumed to have been plugged into the polynomials*. That is important context.

Comment: Ah! I gathered as much. As much that provides some context, it really doesn't help me much with resolving this question. Do you have any suggestions on that front?

Comment: Yes. Your original question missed one thing from the exercise - namely $h_n=n$ is *only* for $n\ge1$, and as a result your $H(t)$ is incorrect. Indeed, the one polynomial $h_{\color{Red}0}(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$ actually is a constant, namely $h_0=1$, regardless of what is plugged into $x_1,x_2,\cdots$.

Comment: So, I get $H(t) = 1 + t/(1-t)^2$ instead?

Comment: Yep. And $E(t)$ and $P(t)$ should be fixed accordingly. Note also, ignoring symmetric polynomials for the moment, there is an algebraic condition on a rational function $f(t)$ that is equivalent to its power series having periodic (of period $d$) coefficients. Can you determine that? (There is a slight caveat in that your exercise only wants you to verify $(e_n)_{n\ge1}$ and $(p_n)_{n\ge1}$ are periodic, which means you will have to take the constant term out of $E(t)$ and $P(t)$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would a rational function $f(t)$ look like if its coefficients have period $2$? Well, like

$$ a+bt+at^2+bt^3+\cdots=(a+bt)(1+t^2+t^4+\cdots)=\frac{a+bt}{1-t^2}  $$

That is, a power series' coefficients have period $2$ if and only if it is a rational function expressible as a polynomial of degree $<2$ divided by $1-t^2$. Generalize to other periods.

Note it is asking to show that $(e_n)_{n\ge\color{Red}1}$ and $(p_n)_{n\ge\color{Red}1}$ are periodic, so you will need to take a look at the constant terms of the rational functions $E(t)$ and $P(t)$ before you try to determine if they are of  the appropriate form to conclude periodic power series coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the question, and I thought I should post the answer.

**Sequence of Elementary Symmetric Functions**

$$E(t) = \frac{(1-t)(1+t)^2}{1-t^3} = \frac{1-t^3+t-t^2}{1-t^3}=1+\frac{t-t^2}{1-t^3}$$

$$\text{Therefore, }
e_n= \begin{cases}
1 & n = 3k+1\\
-1 & n = 3k+2\\
0 & n = 3k+3
\end{cases}
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall k \geq 0$$

**Sequence of Power Sum Symmetric Functions**

$$P(t) = \frac{(1+t)^2}{(1-t)(1+t^3)}=\frac{(1+t+t^2)(1+t)^2}{(1-t^3)(1+t^3)}=\frac{1 + 3t + 4t^2 + 3t^3 + t^4}{1-t^6}$$

$$\implies P(t) = 1+\frac{3t + 4t^2 + 3t^3 + t^4 + t^6}{1-t^6}$$

$$\text{Therefore, }
p_n= \begin{cases}
3 & n = 6k+1\\
4 & n = 6k+2\\
3 & n = 6k+3\\
1 & n = 6k+4\\
0 & n = 6k+5\\
1 & n = 6k+6
\end{cases}
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall k \geq 0$$

Comment: That's right! ${}$

Comment: Thanks a ton for the hint and discussion!